# Leaflet Tilelayer from Mapbox with URL restrictions

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, security, mapbox-studio, react

I’m having great difficulty with this topic.
I’m building a Gatsby/React mapping web app for the Swiss paddlesports community ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/binghamchris/paddelbuch)) using Leaflet to load a custom tile layer from Mapbox.

I’d like to add [URL restrictions](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/guides/tokens/) to my Mapbox token for security. However I can’t figure out how to get Leaflet to send a Referer header to Mapbox to enable this.
I found [Mapbox tiles not showing on Leaflet map using Google Chrome](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379787) from @pfalbaum where it looks like they had this working, however so far I can’t figure out how they did this

Can anyone offer any advice on how to use URL-restricted Mapbox tokens with Leaflet?

Comment: Browsers send the `referer` header by themselves. Inspect your network requests.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this, and in case its useful for anyone else thought I'd offer the solution here!

The issue turned out to have nothing to do with Leaflet or Mapbox, but instead to be about Gatsby Cloud's hosting configuration. It defaults to setting a Referrer-Policy of `same-origin`, which instructs the browser not to send the `referer` header on requests to other domains.

The defaults can be changed using the [gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud/) plugin. I used the following configuration in `gatsby-config.js` to retain the other security defaults while setting the Referrer-Policy to `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud`,
      options: {
        mergeSecurityHeaders: false,
        allPageHeaders: [
          "X-Frame-Options: DENY",
          "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block",
          "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff",
          "Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Hope this is helpful for someone

Comment: very very helpful - thanks